# Migrate OTRS database from PostgreSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, otrs

[OTRS](https://www.otrs.com/) supports PostgreSQL and MySQL databases. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 for my OTRS 3.2 but I want to migrate to MySQL 5.5. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after more research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql) question. So this is what I did:

The Server is a Debian 7 server. I connected from Windows 7.

- Installed ODBC PostreSQL driver (described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql.html))
- Installed MySQL Workbench
- Connected to the server using [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
- Added tunnels to the SSH connection for port 3306 (MySQL) and port 5432 (PostgreSQL) so I can access both server daemons from remote in a secure way
- Setted up the ODBC connection in Windows (using PostgreSQL Unicode)
- Started the Migration Wizard in MySQL Workbench (described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql.html))
- After data migration is completed, I changed the DB settings in /etc/otrs/database.pm
- Restarted Apache to apply changes
- Tried it - worked!

Only problem at the moment is, that umlauts (üöäß) doesn't get correctly imported from mail.